# Escape double quotes in string inside awk pattern

Tags: bash, awk

In my bash script, at some point, I have some like:

```
<mycommand> | awk '
    ...
    $1 == "array" { test = 1 }
    END { if (test) run() }
    function run() {
        print "Messages:", _msg

        cmd="curl -s \""URL"\" -F \"param1="_param1"\" -F \"message="_msg"\" > /dev/null "
        system(cmd);

        fflush()
    }
'
```

so when `run()` executes, it prints something and then sends a system `curl` to somewhere!

My problem is that the `_msg` variable is a string having multiple `"` so the output could be something like:

```
"Messages:": "text1", "text2", "text3"
```

so when I pass it to `curl` I get `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`.

How can I correctly pass it to the `cmd` variable?
I'd need to escape `"` right? How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: please post a [repro].

Comment: @pynexj I posted an example of output and I cannot be more precise than that because `<mycommand>` and the `awk` pattern are both pretty long and based on my specific system. I've just edited the output so that it's easier to understand what I need

Comment: Using `system()` in awk with a non-constant argument is _very_ prone to security issues; I can't advise against it in strong enough terms.

Comment: If your URL contains the literal text `$(rm -rf ~)`, f/e, you're going to have a _very_ bad day. It's feasible to write correct escaping for things substituted into a single-quoted shell context, but not really feasible for a double-quoted context (since shells can and do add new extended syntax). That said, I'd generally just _not use awk_ here; the extra correctness you get from a shell's distinction between syntax and data is worth far more than the performance you give up in a case like this where an external command necessarily makes each iteration slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add theese lines:

```
gsub(/\\/, "\\\\", _msg);
gsub(/"/, "\\\"", _msg);
```

just before `cmd` variable construction.

The first line add `\` before each `\`.

The second line add `\` before each `"`.